# Logitech Marble Mouse - Linux Scroll Modifier Setup

Tags: linux, mouse

In Linux, how do I setup a Logitech Marble Mouse so that the would-be 'back' button is changed to a scroll modifier? IE: Hold the 'back' button down and now the track ball controls scroll.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using an Arch derivative (Antergos) and this config was derived from their [Marble Mouse wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logitech_Marble_Mouse).

Add the following to the **/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf** file...

```
# Section added for scroll with Marble Mouse
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "Marble Mouse"
    MatchProduct    "Logitech USB Trackball"
    Driver          "libinput"
    Option          "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 9"
    Option          "ScrollMethod" "button"
    Option          "ScrollButton" "8"
    Option          "MiddleEmulation" "on"
EndSection
```

Note that the back button operation has been disabled because it would occasionally fire when trying to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `evdev` driver. To do so add following to a new `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-marble-mouse.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier  "Marble Mouse"
        MatchProduct "Logitech USB Trackball"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
        Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
        Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
        Option "EmulateWheelButton" "8"
        Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
        Option  "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
        Option  "Emulate3Buttons" "true"
EndSection
```

Above configuration works for me on Ubuntu 18.04 but it does not on Xubuntu 18.04 running on a ThinkPad R60. For the latter I have to use the `libinput` config posted above by Peter.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following config (similar to @PeterL, but does not disable the back button)

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-libinput.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
     Identifier "Marble Mouse"
     MatchProduct "Logitech USB Trackball"
     Driver "libinput"
     Option "ScrollMethod" "button"
     Option "ScrollButton" "8"
     Option "AccelSpeed" "1"
     # Option "TransformationMatrix" "2.4 0 0 0 2.4 0 0 0 1"
EndSection
```

The commented TransformationMatrix allows to skip pixels and move faster, but I prefer to change the DPI as below instead.

- Set a custom DPI through /etc/udev/hwdb.d/71-mouse-local.hwdb

```
# Logitech Marble Mouse
#id obtained by: mouse-dpi-tool  /dev/input/event4
mouse:usb:v046dpc408:name:Logitech USB Trackball:
# keep space below
 MOUSE_DPI=100@125
```

and then `udevadm hwdb --update`, `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger` and unplug, plug mouse.
The DPI of 100 may be too sensitive for some, you could replace by 200@125.